# SQL Server Management Studio can't open DTS Package

Tags: sql-server, windows, dts

I am running SQL Server Management Studio 2008 on Windows 7.  I am unable to open a SQL Server 2000 DTS package from SQL Server Management Studio 2008.  I have tried going through all the steps that I have found online as far as installing the SQL Server 2005 Backwards Compatibility and the DTS Design Components, but none of it works.  I have even gone through the steps to replace .dlls in the installation directory from some of the posts that I have found.

Is this actually even possible to open a SQL Server 2000 DTS package from within SQL Server 2008 Management Studio on Windows 7?

Comment: I haven't looked into this, but 2000 is really old. Can you recreate the 2000 dts in ssis 08 ?

Comment: Google this "dts 2000 to ssis 2008 migration". Try this link - http://www.infosys.com/microsoft/resource-center/Documents/DTS-SSIS-2008-migration.pdf

Answer (score 0):

No, to the best of my knowledge, what you explicitly describe is not possible (my SSMS crashes when I try).

However, if you are looking to migrate the package from DTS to SSIS, you need to run the DTS Migration Wizard.  I recommend doing this from BIDS:

- Start BIDS 2008
- Create an Integration Services Project
- Right-click SSIS Packages and choose "Migrate DTS 2000 Package"
- Follow Wizard instructions

You can access the wizard through SSMS2008, but ultimately I found it much easier to start in BIDS, and then import the finished product into SQL using SSMS2008.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the same thing and found this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ramoji/archive/2008/10/16/how-to-open-dts-packages-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Never got chance to try it unfortunately as I've been told just to use one of the older machines we have... Hopefully it will help someone though.